# What's the best option to reset a filter?

Tags: gui-design, filter, multi-selection, faceted-search

I'm currently working on a faceted search and I'm wondering what is the best way to reset a filter. Please see my sketches below for a better understanding:

**1. Add a 'All' checkbox at the top of the list (selected by default).**

Example: [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/)

[image: All checkbox][image: All not selected]

**2. Add a 'View all *filter name*' link at the top of the list (once the user has ticked at least one checkbox).**

Example: [eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/)

[image: View all filter name]

**3. Add a 'Clear all' link at the top of the list (once the user has ticked at least one checkbox).**

Example: [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/)

[image: Clear all link]

**4. Add a 'Reset' button in the filter header (once the user has ticked at least one checkbox).**

[image: Reset button]

Note: a 'reset all' button is available at the top of the filter options to reset all filters at once.

Answer (score 4):

> 1 Add a 'All' checkbox at the top of the list (selected by default).

I would advise against the *All* checkbox, as it's against the intended use of checkboxes. If the checkbox is checked, no other checkbox should be able to be checked, as you can't display both **All** and a filter.

> 2 Add a 'View all filter name' link at the top of the list (once the user has ticked at least one checkbox).

Looks too much of a link to a different page than a CTA. Also doesn't look like a form control at all (you chose to use form controls for filtering, so you should be consistent there.

> 3 Add a 'Clear all' link at the top of the list (once the user has ticked at least one checkbox).

Same as for 2

> 4 Add a 'Reset' button in the filter header (once the user has ticked at least one checkbox).

That's the one I would opt for. The button is a form control that's obviously connected with the other form controls. Plus it is outside of the area to *apply* filters but clearly within the filter scope.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just to be clear: if the 'all' checkbox is ticked, the user would have the possibility to tick any other checkboxes but this action would untick the 'all' checkbox. I trying to find an example of site using this pattern.

Comment: Yes I imagined it that way, but as written, that's against the use of checkboxes. Checkboxes shouldn't be used for mutually exclusive items.

Comment: The most common use of the "All" checkbox I experienced is: click on "All" all the checkboxes (including the "All" one). After that, unselecting an option also unchecks the "All" checkbox (but all the other ones stay checked). I find it not common that only the "All" button is checked.

Answer (score 1):

The "all" checkbox is the best option, but it should be displayed in such a way that the relationship between them is clear (this is not the case in your screenshot)

Perhaps display it as a "root" node, with the other checkboxes indented under (treeview style):

[image]

Another way to achieve the effect is having it in the header of a table like this:

[image]

Comment: Having one "Select all" button has a double purpose: click once to select everything, click twice to unselect everything: easy reset !

Comment: In my opinion the "All" option is a necessary option that saves user time and also it usage is standard. The question is to implement as a checkbox or a link, in this case I  would choose the link and the checkbox in a top header (with a different format)

Answer (score 0):

The options to have a 'Select All' and 'Clear All' are not very useful unless you find out that most of the user using the filter would want to be selecting all of the company names very often (which as it seems to be very unlikely, by the way you mention the question).

So a button to Reset would be ideal here. Having this button will:

~ Help users to instantly remove the filters added in a simple way. 
~ Allow the users to deselect their selections easily when they would want to apply different filter selections.

The select all and deselect all options would be helpful when you have high numbers of selections (check boxes in 50's or 100's - ex: gmail inbox)

Answer (score 0):

My five cents for filter and the reset-all option

**Filter based in a checkbox list with a scroll**
[image: checklist with scroll]

**Filter based in a paginated checkbox list (with static un/selectAll links)**
[image: checkbox list static un-select links]

**Filter based in a paginated checkbox list (with dynamic un/selectAll links)**

Note that reset/All and show more/less is "intelligent
[image: checkbox list dynamic un-select links]

**Filter based in list and chips**

"Select All" moves all entries to chip area
[image: list and chips]